# How to draw points and lines on a Chart in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, drawing

I need to make a program that draws a line in a Cartesian plane with Winforms. My data entry method is to enter coordinates in the `TextBox` controls marked **X** and **Y**, but my question in general is about representing points on a chart and connecting them to draw a line.

[image: Dialog layout]

Comment: You only have one set of X and Y (one point). You'd need at least two points to form a line. One option might be to have a list of points.

Comment: Maybe the first time you click `button1` it adds a point to the graph, then, the second time you click `button1`, it adds a second point and joins them together with a line segment.  Perhaps each subsequent click adds another point and extends the line strip.  You'll likely want a way to select, edit and delete existing points too.

Comment: Alternatively, a non-vertical line is sometimes expressed in the form `y = mx + b`.  Perhaps you could permit the user to enter `m` and `b` rather than `x` and `y`.  Given that equation, two such constants fully specify any non-vertical line of infinite length.

Comment: You have the origin/start points, which I take it would be (0,0), so then you just need then end points (x, y)

There are ways of drawing the lines using the pen functionality.  Also there used to be Line controls, but I think these are deprecated now.

Comment: Is your Cartesian plane one image?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` is one approach to doing this. I've used it production code and found it feature-rich and robust.

For **.Net Core** either install `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` as a [NuGet pre-release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages#installing-and-updating-pre-release-packages) version (along with `System.Data.SqlClient` as a dependency) ***or*** one of the 3rd-party derivatives that port it. *Make sure the **[x] Include Prerelease** box is checked when you search for NuGets.* I tested this answer using both .Net Core 3 ([clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cartesian-for-net-core-3-vs-2019.git)) and .Net Core 6 ([clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cartesian-for-net-core-6-in-vs-2022.git)). If you're still using **.NET Framework** it's already built-in and requires no external packages. (That version I've used *a lot*.)

I've put together a basic example of a chart that adds a point at the crosshairs for every click of the mouse, and clears all the points when double-clicked. To answer the question you asked, how to **draw a line with textbox**, just look in the code where points are added to the series and do take the same actions using values from your textboxes.

[image: drawing points on cartesian graph]

---

**MainForm CTOR**

A `Panel` has been placed on the `MainForm` to contain the `Chart` which gets set up in the `MainForm` CTor. The `Crossing` properties are set to 0 so that the X-Y is centered. The `IsMarksNextToAxis` properties are set to `false` to put the labels at the sides and bottom. Setting these to `true` will make it look more like your post.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _chart = new Chart{ Dock = DockStyle.Fill, };
    _series = new Series
    {
        Name = "Series1",
        Color = Color.Green,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsXValueIndexed = false,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        BorderWidth = 2, // In a line chart, this is the width of the line.
    };
    _series.Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = true });

    _chartArea = new ChartArea
    {
        AxisX =
        {
            Minimum = -10,
            Maximum = 10,
            Interval = 1,
            IsMarksNextToAxis = false,
            IsLabelAutoFit = false,
            Crossing = 0,
            LineWidth = 1,
            MajorGrid = {  Interval = 1, LineColor = Color.LightBlue, LineWidth = 1 },
            Enabled = AxisEnabled.True,
        },
        AxisY =
        {
            Minimum = -10,
            Maximum = 10,
            Interval = 1,
            IsMarksNextToAxis = false,
            IsLabelAutoFit = false,
            Crossing = 0,
            LineWidth = 1,
            MajorGrid = {  Interval = 1, LineColor = Color.LightBlue, LineWidth = 1 },
            Enabled = AxisEnabled.True,
        },
    };

    _chart.ChartAreas.Add(_chartArea);
    _series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Cross;
    _chart.Series.Add(_series);

    _chartArea.CursorX.LineColor = Color.LightCoral;
    _chartArea.CursorX.Interval = 0.01;
    _chartArea.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;

    _chartArea.CursorY.LineColor = Color.LightCoral;
    _chartArea.CursorY.Interval = 0.01;
    _chartArea.CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;

    panel.Controls.Add(_chart);
    #if false
    // Draw diagonal
    for (int i = -10; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        _series.Points.AddXY(i, i);
    }
    #endif
    _chart.MouseClick += onChartClick;
    _chart.MouseDoubleClick += onChartDoubleClick;
    _chart.MouseMove += onChartMouseMove;
}
```

---

**Events**

Use the cursor position to add a new point to the series.

```
private void onChartClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _series.Points.AddXY(_chartArea.CursorX.Position, _chartArea.CursorY.Position);
}
```

Clears the series on a double-click.

```
private void onChartDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _series.Points.Clear();
    _series.Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = true });
}
```

Moves the crosshairs:

```
private void onChartMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _chartArea.CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(e.Location, true);
    _chartArea.CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(e.Location, true);
}
```

---

**NuGets**

[image: installed nuget]