# How to draw line(point) chart in winform c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, charts, linechart

I'm trying to make a winform application that draw data load from database into a data grid view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lohC9.png)
I want the weight(kg) as X axis, and net weight as Y axis; and using a chart type "Line".It should create list red point (X,Y), and chart will draw line between them.
But the chart is drawing like pillar chart, and i dont know how to fix it. I

Here is my method code to draw the chart

```
public Chart ConvertToChart(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    
        // Create a new series for the chart
        Series series = new Series();
        series.Name = "Data Series";
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        // Add data points to the series
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            // Get the data from the DataGridView
            int xValue = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
            int yValue = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);

            // Add the data point to the series
            series.Points.AddXY(xValue, yValue);
        }

        // Add the series to the chart
        chart1.Series.Add(series);

        // Return the chart
        return chart1;
    
    }
```

I expect it would be like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGkaO.png)
Any help is much appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help answer your question> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73212568/5438626

Answer (score 0):

Add Chart Control from Visual Studio to your Windows form application (Drag and drop the control)

Note: The chart controls have been deprecated in VS 2022.

Refer to the below code :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace ChartExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChart();
        }

        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            // Setting up chart parameters
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            chartArea.AxisX.Title = "X Axis";
            chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Y Axis";
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

           
            Series series = new Series();
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line; // or SeriesChartType.Point
            series.Name = "MySeries";

            // Add some data points 
            series.Points.AddXY(1, 10);
            series.Points.AddXY(2, 20);
            series.Points.AddXY(3, 15);
            series.Points.AddXY(4, 25);

            // Add the series to the chart
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *The chart controls have been deprecated in VS 2022*: nope, nothing to do with Visual Studio. The Chart component has been removed in .NET. Still there in .NET Framework

Comment: may u don't know, there is a nuget packet name winforms.DataVisualization that allow us install chart feature in .NET core.